# Unable to run custom llvm pass via clang

Tags: clang, llvm

I have a custom LLVM pass that runs successfully using `opt` but I'm having trouble running it via clang.  The command -

```
clang++ -O1 -disable-O0-optnone -fpass-plugin=~/mypass.so -mllvm -passes=my-pass-name
```

gives

> clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-passes=my-pass-name'".

As suggested [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56137#issuecomment-1200957606) I tried adding `-Xclang -load -Xclang ~/mypass.so"`
and got

> Bad options: -load

I'm using clang 16. What am I missing?